# List index out of range every time i use if?

Tags: python

```
v = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10]

f = [2, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12]

def new(v,f):

    i = 0
    j = 0
    u=[0]*12
    for k in range(12):
          if(v[i]<=f[j]):
              u[k]+=v[i]
              i+=1
          elif(f[j]<=v[i]):
                 u[k]+=f[j]
                 j+=1
    print(u)
new(v, f)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Matheus/PycharmProjects/untitled/dsfdsfs.py", line 15, in

```
new(v, f)
```

File "C:/Users/Matheus/PycharmProjects/untitled/dsfdsfs.py", line 8, in new

```
if(v[i]<=f[j]):
```

IndexError: list index out of range

I cant figure the reason of this error

Comment: After the last element in v: which is 10, every time v[i] will be <= f[j] and you will try to increment i, which will be out of range.

Answer (score 1):

When i=5, the first branch of the if statement is executed, and i is incremented to 6. At the next loop, it tries to compare v[6] to f[j]. This throws the error.

You are better off using a while loop, as you do not know the number of iterations you will require. As lists in python are mutable, it is much easier to use the .append() and .extend() functions to add the values to the end of the array, rather than keeping another counter. Lastly, at the end of the while loop, you can check which list was exhausted, causing the loop to end, and add the rest of the other list  at the end.

Example code:

```
def new(v,f):

    i = 0
    j = 0
    u = []
    # Compare values until one of the lists is exhausted
    while i < len(v) and j < len(f):
        if(v[i]<=f[j]):
              u.append(v[i])
              i+=1
        elif(f[j]<=v[i]):
              u.append(f[j])
              j+=1
    # Check which list was exhausted and add the rest of the other 
    # list on the end of the new list
    if i >= len(v):
        u.extend(f[j:])
    else:
        u.extend(v[i:])
    print(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the length of lists v and f are both only 6 long.
When the code is run, i is incremented past 5 which causes the error.

If you add a try/except block within the for loop and then print out the
values of i, j and k you will see the failure:

```
for k in range(12):
    try:
        ....
    except IndexError as err:
        print(err)
        print("i = ", i)
        print("j = ", j)
        print("k = ", k)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a solution on the K range, finally understood.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to combine the two lists into one sorted list?

This would have been much faster:

```
sorted(v+f)
```

Comment: Yeah, it would. But this code actually comes from a test and the question required this method. But thank you anyway.